# What scriptures describe replacing the Pranayama Mantra with Shlokas?

Tags: ramayana, sri-vaishnava, practice, women, pranayama

When Dvija males do Pranayama, they chant an expanded version of the Gayatri Mantra, known as the Mahasavitri Mantra.  Sri Vaishnava lecturer U. Ve. Mukkur Lakshminarasimhachariar Swami had said [this](http://www.vdssabha.org/32-prescriptions-from-the-vedas-for-a-life-of-abundance):

> strīkaḷum prāṇāyāmam ceyyalām. mantiram kūṟi ceyyāmal, slōkam mūlam payiṟci ceyyalām. rāma mātā kausalyā tēvi prāṇāyāmam ceytirukkiṟāḷ. Avaḷ peṟṟa palaṉ uyarntatu.
>
> Women can also do Pranayama.  **Instead of performing Pranayama with Mantras, they can perform it with Shlokas.**  Sri Rama’s mother, Kausalya, performed Pramayama.  The reward she obtained is priceless.

The Kausalaya part is referring to [this chapter](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga4/ayodhya_4_frame.htm) of the Ayodhya Kanda of the Ramayana, where Kausalya uses Pranayama to pray for Rama’s prosperity.

But I’m interested in the part in bold.  My question is, what scriptures describe women replacing Mantras with Shlokas when doing Pranayama?  And what are the replacement Shlokas?

Comment: This is not strictly correct. While the sandhyavandanam ritual and other rituals uses the expanded-Savitri mantra for pranayama, the ashtakshara japa, and the nitya thiruvaradhana require the ashtakshara based pranayama. Different situations call for different mantras in pranayama.

Comment: @hashable What is the ashtakshara-based pranayama?

Comment: @Ikshvaku Pranayama using the ashtakshara mantra. For an example, see #8 on page 7 of this manual http://prapatti.com/slokas/english/laghu_aaraadhanam.pdf

Comment: @hashable Thanks

Comment: Vaikunta-Vasi is the right title.. or just omit any mention of 'late' altogether, it's just some fancy english construct

Comment: Women can always do Pranayama and so it is not a news. Women can be initiated as per Tantras and then during Upasana they do Mula-Mantra Pranayama (Pranayama using the mantra they are initiated into) as is usual with everyone else. Only during Sandhya they use Gayatri because that is the mantra they are going to practice during that particular ritual. For other rituals mantras are different.